# Illegal State Exception in Android Startup sometimes

Tags: marketing-cloud, android

I am receiving a difficult to debug error upon application start up. I have recently updated the sales force sdk from

```
'com.exacttarget.etpushsdk:etsdk:4.9.4@aar'
```

to

```
'com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:5.1.3'
```

Notifications seem to appear sometimes, however more frequently upon app startup I am seeing the same Illegal state exception happening from inside the MarketingCloudSDK.

Init code:

```
            MarketingCloudSdk.init(ShowtimeApplication.instance, getSalesForceConfig().build() , new MarketingCloudSdk.InitializationListener() {
            @Override
            public void complete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                if (!initializationStatus.isUsable()){
                    UberLog.e("MarkingCloudSdk", " Initialization error" , " Status: " + initializationStatus.toString());
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

Builder retreival:

```
    @NonNull
private MarketingCloudConfig.Builder getSalesForceConfig() {
    MarketingCloudConfig.Builder configbuilder = MarketingCloudConfig.builder();
    configbuilder.setApplicationId(mEtAppId)
            .setAccessToken(mEtAccessToken)
            .setGcmSenderId(mGcmProjectNumber)
            .setAnalyticsEnabled(true)    // ET Analytics, default = false
            .setPiAnalyticsEnabled(true)         // Web & Mobile Analytics, default = false
            .setGeofencingEnabled(false)
            .setNotificationSmallIconResId(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
            .setNotificationBuilder(new NotificationManager.NotificationBuilder() {
                @Override
                public NotificationCompat.Builder setupNotificationBuilder(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull NotificationMessage notificationMessage) {
                    UberLog.i("MarketingCloud", "Notification builder");
                    NotificationMessage message = notificationMessage;
                    //  String title = message.payload().getString("title",null) == null ? message.payload().getString("title",null): message.title();
                    // String subtitle = message.payload().getString("subtitle",null) == null ? message.payload().getString("subtitle",null): message.alert();
                    String mess = message.alert();
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify);
                    // builder.setContentTitle(title);
                    builder.setContentText(mess);
                    //  builder.setSubText(subtext);

                    // the notification builder is returned here.
                    return builder;
                }
            })
            .setNotificationLaunchIntentProvider(this);
    return configbuilder;
}
```

The Exception I am seeing on multiple devices upon application install and run:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.showtime.standalone, PID: 30469
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/[APPPACKAGE]/databases/storagedb.db
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1268)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1144)
                  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.a.c.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.a.c.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.a.c.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.RegionMessageManager.f(Unknown Source)
                  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.RegionMessageManager.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.b.c.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.b.c.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.b.c$a.onReceive(Unknown Source)
                  at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
                  at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
                  at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: I was initializing the sdk more than once, once I stopped that happening this error didn't appear again. I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Re-initializing v5.x versions of the SDK should not present a problem.  Question: from where are you initializing the SDK?  It should be initialized in your application's Application Class' `onCreate` method.  Failing to do so will also lead to another problem you alluded to "notifications seem to appear sometimes."